# Installing Tomcat 7 - no JAVA_HOME while JDK is installed

Tags: raspbian, java

I'm trying to get Tomcat7 running on a Raspberry Pi B+. I get an error message saying that JAVA_HOME is not set. I guess that if I set it in Bash, it won't load on startup, or am I wrong there?

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
[FAIL] no JDK found - please set JAVA_HOME ... failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript tomcat7, action "start" failed.
```

JDK is installed:

```
ls -al /usr/lib/jvm/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 mrt 13 14:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 72 root root 12288 mrt 13 14:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  4096 mrt 13 14:23 jdk-7-oracle-armhf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1917 sep 25  2013 .jdk-7-oracle-armhf.jinfo
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  4096 feb 16 13:31 jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2155 mrt 22  2014 .jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt.jinfo
```

I;ve created the file /etc/profile.d/jdk_home

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/
```

After a restart this doesn't change anything.

How can I get this working?

Comment: If you're using the default graphical login (`lightdm`), `/etc/profile` and other bash login shell scripts never get sourced, because you never actually start a login shell (different DM's have different policies about this...).  Try `/etc/environment` instead (there's probably nothing in it currently).

Comment: I use the commandline only right now. After a restart, $JAVA_HOME returned the right result, but Tomcat doesn't see it. Still the same error. Tomcat is a system service, so it should load at startup, independent of logins.

Comment: @goldilocks I tried to set `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment`, but the system still starts with an error that the variable is not set (during startup).

Answer (score 1):

Look into /etc/init.d/tomcat7 startup file, you'll see it requires a **default-java** link against your JDK directory.

`$ cd /usr/lib/jvm
 $ sudo ln -s jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt default-java`

Done - now you can start your tomcat7 instance.

Comment: I still get the `no JDK found - please set JAVA_HOME` message, even with the link. I added `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt` to `.bashrc` in `/home/pi`, `/root` and in `/etc/environment`. I get the message on startup as well as when trying to start Tomcat using `sudo service tomcat7 start`.